# How to write this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I have a problem when I write this sentence:

"However, considering the fact many language courses failed their students, we feel motivated to research further."

I want to add examples to make this sentence clearer but these examples are quite long. Like:

1. English was the worst performed subject in the recent exam.
2. Many students remember nothing after an eight-week course.

How should I insert these 2 examples? (like "....failed their students, [example 1] [example 2], we feel motivated to....")

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly you want to say by organising these sentences.Moreover, in the first sentence, what do you mean by "many language courses failed their students" ? Does the courses failed the students  or the students failed in the courses ?

Comment: @Leth I mean "Many courses let their students down because they spent hours learning but didn't gain much."

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using "however" at the beginning of a sentence.

The question is not clear. You ask about "this sentence" and you ask about adding examples. The examples are lengthy, so I suggest making them a list just as you do here.

One possible version of the sentence is:

> Since many language courses have failed their students, we feel motivated to do further research of issues such as the following:

Followed by the list. That version assumes that "many language courses have failed their students" has been previously explained. Since I don't know the context I am not sure how the word "however" is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid phrases like “the fact that”. They only add unneeded words.  You are right to seek compact expression.  Don’t be afraid to write multiple short sentences.  For example:

> English was the worst performed subject in the recent exam and many
>   students remember nothing after an eight-week course. These, [and
>   other] failures motivate us to further research.

One way to get the thought into a single sentence is to squeeze the examples into noun phrases:

> Low exam scores and the students’ poor knowledge retention rates
>   motivate us to further research.

I agree with Leth's comment. You will be more persuasive if you lay out the facts, and *then* make the case that your research will determine the cause.

Comment: Can't it be like:- ....failures motivate us **for** further research.?